# Dinosaur Reptile Skin

Tags: texturing, materials, sculpting

I made a dinosaur and I want to put a reptile skin on it. I tried it with sculpting and image texture brushes but then it looks blurry. I can't increase the resolution because I have already 4 steps multi resolution. I also tried it with texture painting but then I only have a texture without the 3d. anyone can help please?

[image]

https://i.imgur.com/a/n6u9L.jpg

Comment: Could you show us reference for this skin? What exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: yes like this https://www.google.de/search?q=indominus+rex&rlz=1C1CHBF_deDE710DE710&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjA-7O_7ffYAhXFDewKHdKzAkUQ_AUICigB&biw=1280&bih=600#imgrc=uqG-hiJVc9tUqM:

Comment: First of all add picture to the question, secondly you can't see clearly skin on the one from link.

Comment: can u see it better here? https://www.google.de/search?q=indominus+rex&rlz=1C1CHBF_deDE710DE710&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjA-7O_7ffYAhXFDewKHdKzAkUQ_AUICigB&biw=1280&bih=600#imgrc=p10YsM5DsQ7BoM:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I'm not an expert on blender, just someone who messes with it occasionally, but i think a good way to do this would be to use a normal map.

Just in case you don't know what that is, it's like your standard image texture, but it tells the light how to interact with as if it's 3d. This can make an object look like is has more geometry than it actually does. here are a couple of examples of how they look

[image]
https://i0.wp.com/unitycoder.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/poormans_normal_specular_map_generator_unity3d_big.jpg

[image]
http://wiki.polycount.com/w/images/thumb/c/c9/Normalmap_stairs.jpg/1406px-Normalmap_stairs.jpg

So what you do is you pair a normal map with a standard color texture map and boom. it can look pretty nice. There are plenty of tutorials on youtube that show you how to use all kinds of other texture maps than just your color ones.

They aren't usually used with a high poly sculpt, but i bet with a little searching and adaptation of standard stuff you can do it.

anyway that's my piece of advise, again I'm no professional but maybe this will help.